# How to add woocomerce delivery time information on product page with certain conditions

Tags: php, woocommerce

my applogies for being a baby php programmer.

I am trying to modify a php code to snipet to display on woocommerce product page (just below the add to cart button), order delivery time infomation, based on the following format and conditions:

**Format**

Order by 9PM **{$order_by}** for delivery on **{$del_day}**

**Conditions**

1. If days is between Mondays to Saturdays; after 9PM should print out the message

> Order by 9PM **{today}** for delivery on **{same day}**
> 2. If days is between Mondays to Saturdays; before 9PM should print out the message

> Order by 9PM **{tommorow}** for delivery on **{tommorow}**

3. If the weed day is sunday; after 9PM or before 9PM, should print out the message

> Order by 9PM **{today}** for delivery on **{next monday}**

Here is what I have done so far

```
    
function delivery_estimate() {
   date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );  
    
   // if SUN delivery will be MON
   if ( date( 'N' ) >= 7 ) {
      $del_day = date( "l jS F", strtotime( "next monday" ) );
      $order_by = "today";
   } 
    
   // if MON/SAT after 8PM delivery will be day after tomorrow
   elseif ( date( 'H' ) >= 20 ) {
      $del_day = date( "1 jS F", strtotime( "tomorrow" ) );
      $order_by = "tomorrow";
   } 
    
   // if MON/SAT before 8PM delivery will be TOMORROW
   else {
      $del_day = date( "2 jS F", strtotime( "today" ) );
      $order_by = "today";
   }
 
   $html = "<br><div class='woocommerce-message' style='clear:both'>Order by 8PM {$order_by} for delivery on {$del_day}</div>";
    
   echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Is the HTML not appear? ... Not sure how the function is being called, but should it `return` the `$html` instead of `echo` to display where called?

Comment: thanks for your response. It actually displays but not working following the conditions I just describe abaove. Please can you re-edit the code or make adjust to in the code to work following the conditions above?